# Current state of Gene Therapy

Tags: genetics, dna, gene-expression, genomics, gene-therapy

I am interested in learning about attempts to treat adult individuals suffering from a genetic disease in which the underlying changes in the DNA of the gene are understood.

(i) Are there approaches that use drugs or do they use DNA corresponding to the normal DNA?

(ii) Are there attempts to reverse the condition or only ammeliorate it?

(iii) How near is such gene therapy to clinical use and for which diseases?

Comment: OK, wow, that's a lot of questions. Theoretically, if you can edit each and every somatic (body) cell in the body, you can cure the person. That's a tad bit difficult, to be honest. However, if the patient were a foetus, then we wouldn't need to make those many edits. However, if the gonadal (sex) cells of the body are edited, the future offspring of the patient would not have the condition. You're going to have to be a bit more specific with this 'condition'.

Comment: What you're interested in is a form of Gene Therapy. This is extremely difficult. There are many strategies currently being researched, and the best strategy to use probably depends on the specific genetic condition. In your question, you mention gene editing, which uses CRISPR/Cas9, Zinc Finger Nucleases, or TALEN endonucleases to cut DNA at a specific site, then relies on the cell's DNA repair mechanism to fix the cut, hopefully with a correct of the gene provided alongside the nuclease enzyme. This is very inefficient in cell culture, but at least in cell culture you can find a good cell

Comment: and grow as many copies as you need. In a living organism, it becomes much harder. Most of the gene editing nucleases are delivered as a molecule of DNA or mRNA that can then make the enzyme once it gets into a cell. However, delivery of DNA to cells in vivo is an incredible challenge. Modified viruses are more effective than nonviral systems, but have limited carrying capacity and possible immunological effects. Nonviral systems are in still in their infancy after over 20 years of effort. A nonviral gene delivery system must protect DNA from destruction by nucleases, get the DNA into the

Comment: right cell type, and then get that DNA into the nucleus. Once in the nucleus, the DNA can make the protein, in our case a gene editing nuclease. Now the nuclease must find and cut the bad gene in the right way, if using CRISPR, that requires a small guide RNA to target the enzyme to the right place. Depending on how this RNA is delivered, not all cells that get a copy of the CRISPR gene will get the RNA, so these cells will not have their DNA cut. Using ZFN or TALENS avoids the guide RNA requirement, but often have a worse accuracy rate and can cut the DNA at incorrect positions.

Comment: But the biggest barrier to efficient gene editing is probably homology directed repair. When DNA is cut, your cells have 2 ways to fix it, they can just stick the ends together and fill in the gaps. This usually introduces errors and can often simply destroy a gene, and is usually not desired in gene editing, but it's much more efficient. Homology Directed Repair will take a matching copy of the damaged DNA, usually the corresponding gene on the sister chromatid, and use it to copy the sequence into the damaged DNA. This is what allows gene editing to work, but you have to deliver your good

Comment: DNA alongside the CRISPER gene and the guide RNA. The target cells have to get all three components in the right proportions, and they have to choose the good DNA to repair the damaged genomic DNA. Furthermore, you can't simply select correct cells in an in vivo situation, because killing off 90% or more of the cells will kill the patient, so your delivery efficiencies and repair efficiencies must be much much higher than we've achieved in gene delivery so far.

Comment: @user137 You couldv'e just put this as an answer, I believe you're right!

Comment: @user137 yeah man that's too many comments. Putting an answer instead will increase the chances that someone will read all of it ;)

Comment: @user137 Please do not use the comments to write an answer. Put these comments together, add a few references and you have an answer.

Comment: I've edited the title of the question to include the term, Gene Therapy, which is what your question is about. I have also clarified it. The 43 year-old man may be perhaps someone you know, but isn't relevant here.

Answer (score 2):

The scope of this question is too wide to be answered on Biology SE. However I will give you very brief answers to your questions (as I have rephrased them) and point you towards some sources of basic information on the Internet. After reading these you may wish to return with more specific questions. I have also briefly summarized some of the problems which it is useful to be aware of before reading details of specific approaches to gene therapy,.

**Answers**

> (i) Some approaches involve attempts to replace a defective gene with
> a functional gene or add the latter to the patient’s DNA. Others
> involve drugs, often nucleic acid in nature.
>
> (ii) Current efforts often have the more modest aim of ameliorating the disease, although there are also efforts to reverse the condition.
>
> (iii) Gene therapy is not yet in general clinical use, although for some diseases (e.g. Severe Combined Immune Deficiency and Chronic Granulomatus Disorder) there have been reports of success in limited clinical trials.

**General Reading**

I am not an expert in this area, but by Googling for ‘Gene Therapy’ I came up with the following pages that you may find helpful.

> [Your Genome](http://www.yourgenome.org/facts/what-is-gene-therapy)
>
> [University of Utah: Approaches to Gene Therapy](http://learn.genetics.utah.edu/content/genetherapy/gtapproaches/)
>
> [American Society of Cell and Gene
> Therapy](http://www.asgct.org/about_gene_therapy/diseases.php)

You may also be interested to read about the currently controversial drug, [Eteplirsen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eteplirsen).

**Problems in Gene Therapy**

Rather than giving you details of technical approaches to gene therapy, for which you may not have the necessary scientific background, I draw your attention to some of the key problems and questions that have to be addressed in this area.

1. Does one need to counteract the harmful effect of a mutant gene product (e.g. sickle cell haemoglobin), or is it sufficient to produce a ‘good’ gene product to remedy a deficit?
2. Is it possible to target new cells or does one have to deal with existing mature cells?
   (Some cells like blood and immune cells are constantly renewing themselves, whereas others like muscle turn over much more slowly. The latter are more difficult to deal with.)
3. How can the DNA (or drug) be deliverdd to the cell, and only to the appropriate cell. (A variety of delivery techniques have been employed in different circumstances.)
4. How can the therapeutic DNA be incorporated into the appropriate position in the genome, and how can one ensure that it is expressed, and that no other genes are affected. (Early attempts at gene therapy using in which DNA was inserted at the wrong position resulted in cancers. However technology here is moving rapidly.)

Comment: "Early attempts at gene therapy using in which DNA was inserted at the wrong position resulted in cancers."  - what are some examples of this?

Comment: @mingyeow The most well-known is the attempt to cure SCID in 2002. See [Gene Therapy (2003) 10, 4–4. doi:10.1038/sj.gt.3301946](http://www.nature.com/gt/journal/v10/n1/full/3301946a.html).

Comment: thank you! this indirectly answers one of my main questions in gene therapy: how is it possible to control the side effects of gene mutation? what  would be your recommended reading for understanding how we are controlling how cells whose genes have been changed are inserted into the target organism's body?

Comment: @mingyeow This isn't really my field, but from general reading I am aware that there is a lot of interest in using CRISPR technology because of its precision. A recent [commentary](http://www.nature.com/gt/journal/v23/n7/full/gt201625a.html) I found surfing might be a good starting point:

Comment: I understand that crispr offers precision in gene editing, but does that also apply to the way cells reproduce those edited genes?

Comment: @mingyeow — The original question was very broad and it was therefore useful to give an answer that was  very general, even though this wasn’t my area. That’s why the question is closed. However as you have more specific concerns, I would suggest that you formulate them carefully into a question of your own and post it here. That way it is more likely to come to the attention of someone who might be able to answer it. (And the answers will be indexed to the benefit of others, which is the way that SE works.)